# Перенос строки в картинках PHP (imagettftext)

Tags: php, строки, изображения

Нужно делать переносы в тексте (переменной $text), имеется такой код, который автоматически уменьшает размер (максимум до 20 — от 30), если он не влазит в картинку:

```
    <?php
    $sizes = getimagesize($bg_path);

    $font = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/fonts/arialbd.ttf";

    $black = imagecolorallocate($bg, 0, 0, 0);

    for($fontSize = 30; $fontSize > 0; $fontSize--) {
        $bbox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $text);

        $x = (imagesx($bg) - $bbox[4]) / 2;
        $y = (imagesy($bg) - $bbox[5]) / 2;

        if($fontSize < 20) {
            exit(json_encode(array("error_text"=> "Текст слишком большой и не может вместиться в картинку.")));
        }

        if($x >= 15) {
            break;
        }
    }

    imagettftext($bg, $fontSize, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);
?>
```

У кого есть идеи или пример кода? Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: (Ширина картинки) - (отступы справа и слева))/(ширина буквы + межбуквенное пространство)= кол-во символов в строке. Текст разбиваем на строки, применяем правила переноса или берите целые слова. (Я с мобильного, а так бы набросал ответ)